# Why are the children failing to die?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I expected the `terminate()` method to kill the two processes:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def foo():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

def bar():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        p_foo = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name='foo')
        p_bar = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, name='bar')
        p_foo.start()
        p_bar.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        p_foo.terminate()
        p_bar.terminate()
        print p_foo
        print p_bar
```

Running the code gives:

```
<Process(foo, started)>
<Process(bar, started)>
<Process(foo, started)>
<Process(bar, started)>
...
```

I was expecting:

```
<Process(foo, stopped)>
<Process(bar, stopped)>
<Process(foo, stopped)>
<Process(bar, stopped)>
...
```

Comment: +1 for nice head line. Could be the title of a heavy metal record.

Comment: Multiprocessing always makes these awkwardly-awesome comments about dying children turning into zombies, killing their parents and stuff. It’s just so great xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [terminate](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) function just send SIGTERM signal to process, but [signals are asynchronous](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/signals.pdf), so you can sleep for some time, or [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) for processes termination(signal receiving).

For example if you add string `time.sleep(.1)` after termination, it probably will be terminated.