# preg_match_all causes children to die

Tags: php, regex, apache

I have a TinyMCE form that accepts copy / paste of images. When you're done putting in your comment, you press "Post" and it submits the form, the content is parsed, and displayed in the on-screen conversation.

I am trying to use preg_match_all to pull the base64 encoded data from the POSTed vars. Most of my patterns work, but this one is causing Apache to crash.

```
<img src="data:image/(png|PNG|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG);base64,([a-zA-Z0-9+/=])*
```

The crash is silent, and the only hint I am getting from Apache / PHP is a single line in the error.log file:

> [error] child died with signal 11

I have narrowed it down to this pattern in preg_match_all and the fact that I have a * after the second group, which consists of a class definition designed to follow the base64 characters to their termination by a quote.

The sample image is available here (text file, base64 encoded):
https://cloud.highpoweredhelp.com/index.php/s/hnIaFmK9vTCOmcU

The only thing I can think of is that the "*" is too greedy and is consuming too much memory. But, there are two problems with that:

1. I increased the memory_limit in php.ini from 128M to 256M without a result, and
2. The file size is only 198K.

System:
Apache v2.2.22 on Debian Wheezy 7.9 
PHP Version: 5.6.16 compiled from source using the following configure:

```
./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2 \
--with-pear=/usr/share/php \
--with-bz2 \
--with-curl \
--with-gd \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-sockets \
--with-libxml-dir \
--with-mysqli \
--with-mysql \
--with-openssl \
--with-regex=php \
--with-readline \
--with-zlib \
--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 \
--enable-soap \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/ \
--with-freetype \
--with-mcrypt=/usr/src/mcrypt-2.6.8 \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
--with-png-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: `(png|PNG|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG)` can be modified to `((?i)png|gif|jpe?g)`.  The `(?i)` allows [case insensitivity](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php) for the current subpattern.  Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mU8uG6/1

Comment: Just a hint, not a solution: your first part (the file extensions) can be simplified: `(png|gif|jpe?g)` with the case insensitive parameter (`i`) appended.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Had not updated the question in a while.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Even better: look to the right (related) questions - [Why are the children failing to die?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942654/why-are-the-children-failing-to-die?rq=1)

Comment: @Jan: Yes, I upvoted that one as well ;-) Also to the guy who said _Could be the title of a heavy metal record._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really intended `([a-zA-Z0-9+/=]*)` instead of `([a-zA-Z0-9+/=])*`

The latter pattern will only get you the final character of the base64 sequence, but appears to cause segmentation faults quite quickly. I was able to crash a command line app with a relatively short string with that pattern:

```
#this segfaulted for me, a shorter string did succeed
$str='<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.str_repeat('0123456789',1000);
if (preg_match('{<img src="data:image/(png|PNG|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG);base64,([a-zA-Z0-9+/=])*}', $str, $match)){
        print "matched";
}
```

The `([a-zA-Z0-9+/=]*)` pattern will capture every character, and won't crash!

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9+/=]*)` may be overkill in the first place.  Something such as `([^"]*)` may suffice.

Comment: The sort of error in OP's regular expression is known as [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  Simply put, there are many *many* ways to group `(pattern)*` and the regex engine wants to find all of them.